# How do I get my function to work more than once?

Tags: python, function

I made the 'response' function to check if the answer to a question was correct or incorrect, then answer accordingly. My issue is that this only works once and after that, it will only output 'INCORRECT' no matter the answer. My knowledge of functions is limited so i can guess the issue lies in my function.

```
ans = 0

def response(ans):
    if ans == 1:
        print("CORRECT")
    else:
        print ("INCORRECT")

q1 = input("Q1: What data type should be used for basic text?\n")
if q1.lower() == ("string"):
    ans += 1
response(ans)

q2 = input("Q2: What symbol is used for multiplication?\n")
if q2 == ("*"):
    ans += 1
response(ans)
```

I have tried various methods of resetting the function after the first question and read many articles on functions but still cant get it to work :/

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-control-flow-tools

Comment: Describe the exact purpose of the variable `ans`. This is your design flaw.

Comment: Feel free to accept any of the 5 answers that someone reading question in the future, should first refer to as a solution. None is also fine if no one single answer addressed it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working a second time is because you need to reset the value of ans back to zero if you're going to run your function again. The value is already at 1 if you answer first question correctly and at the second correct question you increment it to 2. Reset your variable back to zero.

Comment: That answers you exact question buy if your looking for a better solution, you can ask for that as well.

Comment: That made it work tysm!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when it reaches on the 2nd question, the sum of the variable "ans" is now 2, no matter if it is correct or not, or you reset the variable "ans" to 0, or do something like this:

```
def response(ans):
    if ans == 1:
        print("CORRECT")
    else:
        print ("INCORRECT")

ans = 0
q1 = input("Q1: What data type should 
be used for basic text?\n")
if q1.lower() == ("string"):
    ans = 1
else:
    ans = 2
response(ans)

q2 = input("Q2: What symbol is used for multiplication?\n")
if q2 == ("*"):
    ans = 1
else:
    ans = 2
response(ans)
```

Comment: Your code improves the `if` tests by assigning `1` or `2` to `ans`. That means that `ans = 0` is redundant and can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is fine: It accepts a parameter and tests the value of the parameter. Nothing wrong there.

What is wrong, is using the `ans` variable outside the function. (It would be better if you used a different name outside to avoid confusion). You seem to be poking at it in various ways that are simply not appropriate. You initialise it to `0` just once and not before each question. You increment it when testing the answer instead of setting it.

After all that, your function is fine and you should just pass in the test of the answers, since the test evaluates to a boolean value:

```py
def response(ans):
    if ans == 1:
        print("CORRECT")
    else:
        print ("INCORRECT")

q1 = input("Q1: What data type should be used for basic text?\n")
response(q1.lower() == ("string"))

q2 = input("Q2: What symbol is used for multiplication?\n")
response(q2 == ("*"))
```

Sample session output:

```
Q1: What data type should be used for basic text?
string
CORRECT
Q2: What symbol is used for multiplication?
/
INCORRECT
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason for this is that you defined `ans` outside of your function.

This makes `ans` a global variable, rather than a local variable tied to the function scope. That means that `ans` is accessible anywhere in the script, versus only within the function. It also means that when the function ends, `ans` retains the same value last set, rather than getting destroyed at the end of the function by "going out of scope".

Normally, you could try moving the first definition of such a variable into the function. In this case, simply remove it because it's defined as an argument and doesn't need a default value. This should work, for example:

```
def response(ans):
    if ans == 1:
        print("CORRECT")
    else:
        print ("INCORRECT")
```

---

Looking more closely at your inputs:

The global ans will equal 2 if you get q1+q2 right correct. It will equal 1 if you get only either right. It's not really the expected logic. You asked two questions, so a score of 2/2 would be 100%, but your function only checks if ans equals 1.

I might come up with:

```
def response(ans, correct):
    if ans == correct:
        print("CORRECT")
    else:
        print("INCORRECT")
```

or even pass the whole test:

```
def response(ans, test):
    if test(ans):
        print("CORRECT")
    else:
        print("INCORRECT")

response(ans, lambda x: x.lower() == "string")
```

putting it together:

```
def response(ans, test):
    if test(ans):
        print("CORRECT")
        return True
    else:
        print("INCORRECT")
        return False


total_qs = 2
ans = 0

q1r = input("Q1: What data type should be used for basic text?\n")
if response(q1r, lambda x: x.lower() == "string"):
    ans += 1

q2r = input("Q2: What symbol is used for multiplication?\n")
if response(q2r, lambda x: x == "*"):
    ans += 1

if ans == total_qs:
    print("You got all the questions correct!")
else:
    print(f"You got {ans} out of {total_qs} questions correct.")
```

Comment: As Yves said, it's unclear what ans should do, we definitely need to know more about it.

Comment: You still need to reset your variable back to zero after each question, correct?

Comment: @Seagull9824 You should take a look at my recent edit, was a bit hasty with my first posting.

Answer (score -1):

To understand the problem you need to understand "Call by value" and "Call by reference".

TRDR:

If you're passing an argument to function, you have above two options to
provide those arguments.

You can either "pass the variable by reference" in which case the location at which your variable is stored is passed into the function. Languages like C and C++ support this feature by use of pointers and addresses

Whereas the other method is "pass the variable by value". To simplify, in this method the actual variable is not passed to the function instead the copy of the actual variable is passed and whatever changes you make to the variable passed inside the function, those changes won't reflect in the actual variable

For example:

```
ans = 0

def change(ans):
    ans = 10
    print("Inside function")
    print(ans)
    
change(ans)

print("Outside function")
print(ans)
```

Here the output will be:

```
Inside function
10
Ouside function
0
```

This happens because the variable "ans" passed inside the function is not the same variable declared above it's a copy of that variable

You can do something like this if you wanna keep the same code

**SOLUTION:**

```
ans = 0

def response(ans):
    if ans == 1:
        print("CORRECT")
        ans = 0
        return ans
    else:
        print ("INCORRECT")
        ans = 0
        return ans

q1 = input("Q1: What data type should be used for basic text?\n")
if q1.lower() == ("string"):
    ans = 1
ans = response(ans)

q2 = input("Q2: What symbol is used for multiplication?\n")
if q2 == ("*"):
    ans = 1
ans = response(ans)
```

Here we return a new value of ans through the function and assigned the return value to the "ans" outside the function everytime we call the function

I'd recommend you also read more about "Call by value" and "Call by reference"

Comment: You absolute legend. thanks for the detailed explanation G.